# soft delete from an array of objects using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to soft delete an object from array using [mongoose-delete lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-delete)

I Have a schema like that :

```
const mongooseDelete = require('mongoose-delete');

const number = new Schema({
    allocation_date: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now() },
    number: { type: String, required: true },
    virtual_number: { type: String, required: true },
    virtual_number_id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    
});

const schema = new Schema(
    {
        allocation_id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        numbers: { type: [number], required: true },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    },
);

number.plugin(mongooseDelete, { deletedAt : true });
```

exemple data :

```
   {
      "_id": "5f7c14f9388ee9ebc0b28abc",
      "allocation_id": "5_2_9387323_1"
      "numbers": [
        {
          "allocation_date": "2020-10-06T06:55:41.197Z",
          "_id": "5f7c14f997d996f7988fe8cf",
          "number": "*********",
          "virtual_number": "**********",
          "virtual_number_id": *******,
        },
        {
          "allocation_date": "2020-10-06T06:59:41.197Z",
          "_id": "5f7c14f997d996f7988fe8cf",
          "number": "*********",
          "virtual_number": "**********",
          "virtual_number_id": *******
        }
      ],
      "createdAt": "2020-10-06T06:55:53.367Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-10-06T06:55:53.367Z",
    }
```

When I tried to use the delete method as follow  :

```
const deleteNumber = await VirtualNumberAllocation.findOne(
        {
            'numbers.virtual_number': virtualNumber.virtualNumber,
            allocation_id: virtualNumber.allocationID,
        });

const activeVirtualNumber = deleteNumber.numbers.filter(
            (number) => number.virtual_number==virtualNumber.virtualNumber,
        );

await activeVirtualNumber[0].delete();
```

I'm getting this error in console:

```
mongoose: calling `save()` on a subdoc does **not** save the document to MongoDB, it only runs save middleware. Use `subdoc.save({ suppressWarning: true })` to hide this warning if you're sure this behavior is right for your app.
```

Does anyone have experience with soft deleting from an array using the library?